# How do I use Python to format characters like this?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a character that looks like this:

```
[{'Keys': ['AWS Direct Connect'], 'Metrics': {'AmortizedCost': {'Amount': '0.758738186', 'Unit': 'USD'}}}, {'Keys': ['AWS Key Management Service'], 'Metrics': {'AmortizedCost': {'Amount': '0.000099', 'Unit': 'USD'}}}, {'Keys': ['EC2 - Other'], 'Metrics': {'AmortizedCost': {'Amount': '2556.9016995725', 'Unit': 'USD'}}}, {'Keys': ['Amazon Elastic Compute Cloud - Compute'], 'Metrics': {'AmortizedCost': {'Amount': '78956.164624688', 'Unit': 'USD'}}}, {'Keys': ['Amazon Elastic Load Balancing'], 'Metrics': {'AmortizedCost': {'Amount': '25.2072556293', 'Unit': 'USD'}}}, {'Keys': ['Amazon Elastic MapReduce'], 'Metrics': {'AmortizedCost': {'Amount': '6963.88', 'Unit': 'USD'}}}, {'Keys': ['Amazon Relational Database Service'], 'Metrics': {'AmortizedCost': {'Amount': '5263.199999968', 'Unit': 'USD'}}}, {'Keys': ['Amazon Route 53'], 'Metrics': {'AmortizedCost': {'Amount': '0.1', 'Unit': 'USD'}}}, {'Keys': ['Amazon Simple Queue Service'], 'Metrics': {'AmortizedCost': {'Amount': '0.0825688', 'Unit':'USD'}}}, {'Keys': ['Amazon Simple Storage Service'], 'Metrics': {'AmortizedCost': {'Amount': '9.9447263365', 'Unit': 'USD'}}}, {'Keys': ['Amazon Virtual Private Cloud'], 'Metrics': {'AmortizedCost': {'Amount': '46.56945646', 'Unit': 'USD'}}}, {'Keys': ['AmazonCloudWatch'], 'Metrics': {'AmortizedCost': {'Amount': '5.2942831629', 'Unit': 'USD'}}}, {'Keys': ['Tax'], 'Metrics': {'AmortizedCost': {'Amount': '0', 'Unit': 'USD'}}}]
```

I want to format this string like this:

```
{"data":[{"{#KEYS}": "AWS Direct Connect","{#AMOUNT}": "0.758738186"},{"{#KEYS}": "AWS Key Management Service","{#AMOUNT}": "0.000099"},...
]}
```

Can anyone help me with this please?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. What do you imagine are the logical steps to solving the problem? Where exactly are you stuck, and why? What are the rules that tell you how to get from the input to the output - how are they related? Where did the data come from, and what will you do with the result? Is it actually a string, or is it parsed JSON data, or something else? Do you need a string at the end or what? Please read [ask], and try to ask a **specific** question - "Can anyone help me" [does not qualify](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
string = [{'Keys': ['AWS Direct Connect'], 'Metrics': {'AmortizedCost': {'Amount': '0.758738186', 'Unit': 'USD'}}}, {'Keys': ['AWS Key Management Service'], 'Metrics': {'AmortizedCost': {'Amount': '0.000099', 'Unit': 'USD'}}}, {'Keys': ['EC2 - Other'], 'Metrics': {'AmortizedCost': {'Amount': '2556.9016995725', 'Unit': 'USD'}}}, {'Keys': ['Amazon Elastic Compute Cloud - Compute'], 'Metrics': {'AmortizedCost': {'Amount': '78956.164624688', 'Unit': 'USD'}}}, {'Keys': ['Amazon Elastic Load Balancing'], 'Metrics': {'AmortizedCost': {'Amount': '25.2072556293', 'Unit': 'USD'}}}, {'Keys': ['Amazon Elastic MapReduce'], 'Metrics': {'AmortizedCost': {'Amount': '6963.88', 'Unit': 'USD'}}}, {'Keys': ['Amazon Relational Database Service'], 'Metrics': {'AmortizedCost': {'Amount': '5263.199999968', 'Unit': 'USD'}}}, {'Keys': ['Amazon Route 53'], 'Metrics': {'AmortizedCost': {'Amount': '0.1', 'Unit': 'USD'}}}, {'Keys': ['Amazon Simple Queue Service'], 'Metrics': {'AmortizedCost': {'Amount': '0.0825688', 'Unit':'USD'}}}, {'Keys': ['Amazon Simple Storage Service'], 'Metrics': {'AmortizedCost': {'Amount': '9.9447263365', 'Unit': 'USD'}}}, {'Keys': ['Amazon Virtual Private Cloud'], 'Metrics': {'AmortizedCost': {'Amount': '46.56945646', 'Unit': 'USD'}}}, {'Keys': ['AmazonCloudWatch'], 'Metrics': {'AmortizedCost': {'Amount': '5.2942831629', 'Unit': 'USD'}}}, {'Keys': ['Tax'], 'Metrics': {'AmortizedCost': {'Amount': '0', 'Unit': 'USD'}}}]
converted_string = {'data': [{ k : item['Keys'][0] if k == '{#KEYS}' else item['Metrics']['AmortizedCost']['Amount'] for k in ['{#KEYS}', '{#AMOUNT}'] } for item in a]}
```

Output

```
{'data': [{'{#KEYS}': 'AWS Direct Connect', '{#AMOUNT}': '0.758738186'},
  {'{#KEYS}': 'AWS Key Management Service', '{#AMOUNT}': '0.000099'},
  {'{#KEYS}': 'EC2 - Other', '{#AMOUNT}': '2556.9016995725'},
  {'{#KEYS}': 'Amazon Elastic Compute Cloud - Compute',
   '{#AMOUNT}': '78956.164624688'},
  {'{#KEYS}': 'Amazon Elastic Load Balancing', '{#AMOUNT}': '25.2072556293'},
  {'{#KEYS}': 'Amazon Elastic MapReduce', '{#AMOUNT}': '6963.88'},
  {'{#KEYS}': 'Amazon Relational Database Service',
   '{#AMOUNT}': '5263.199999968'},
  {'{#KEYS}': 'Amazon Route 53', '{#AMOUNT}': '0.1'},
  {'{#KEYS}': 'Amazon Simple Queue Service', '{#AMOUNT}': '0.0825688'},
  {'{#KEYS}': 'Amazon Simple Storage Service', '{#AMOUNT}': '9.9447263365'},
  {'{#KEYS}': 'Amazon Virtual Private Cloud', '{#AMOUNT}': '46.56945646'},
  {'{#KEYS}': 'AmazonCloudWatch', '{#AMOUNT}': '5.2942831629'},
  {'{#KEYS}': 'Tax', '{#AMOUNT}': '0'}]}
```

Answer (score -1):

If the list is JSON compliant (ie you used a JSON deserializer to create the list, or the list can be serialized), then you can use the `object_hook` of `json.load` or `json.loads`. Assuming the starting point is a list, then try this:

```py
from json import dumps, loads

my_list = [{"Keys": […], …}, …]

def my_object_hook(obj):
    """return obj with reformatted keys"""
    return {"{#" + k.upper() + "}": v for k,v in obj.items()}

my_desired_list = loads(
    dumps(my_list), object_hook=my_object_hook
)
```